# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: gherkin.formatter.model.Scenario.getId()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I am writing a cucumber code to automate comparison between xml files. But getting 
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: gherkin.formatter.model.Scenario.getId()Ljava/lang/String;**
 when i am running the feature file . I am using gherkin 2.12.2.

**My Feature File**

```
Feature: File Comparator

Scenario Outline: Comparing XML Files

Given I have <XML1> and <XML2> in <Location1> and <Location2>
When I compare <XML1> to <XML2>
Then Both should be the same
Exmaples:

| XML1| location1 | XML2 | location2|

| XML1.xml| C:/Filepath1| XML2.xml| C:/Filepath2|
```

**MY StepDefinition**

```
public class FCStepDefinition {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FCStepDefinition.class);

@Given("^I have ([^\"]*) and ([^\"]*) in ([^\"]*) and ([^\"]*)$")
public static void checkXML1(String xml1, String xml2, String location1, String location2) throws Throwable 
{
    log.info("File name" + xml1 + "and" + xml2 +"from the paths" + location1 + "and" + location2 + "were located");
    System.out.println("File name" + xml1 + "and" + xml2 +"from the paths" + location1 + "and" + location2 + "were located");
}

@When("^I compare ([^\"]*) to ([^\"]*)$")
public static void compareXMLs(String xml1, String location1,String xml2, String location2) throws Exception 
{
    try {
        log.info("Comparing the XML1 to XML2.");
        Assert.assertTrue("\n XML1 is not similar to XML2",XMLComparator.compareXMLs(location1 + xml1, location2 + xml2));
    }

    finally {

    }
}

@Then("^Both should be the same$")
public static void verifyOutput(String expectedSCH, String outputLocation) throws Throwable 
{
    log.info("The Files matches");
}}
```

**My Runner**

```
package cucumber;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

    format = {"pretty", "html:target/html/", "json:target/json/"},
    features = "src/features", 
    strict = true
    )
public class FCRunner {

}
```

Comment: Do you know where does it fails exactly? Does it even start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pulling in an earlier version of Gherkin somewhere. In Gherkin 2.11.5, for example, that method did not yet exist while [in 2.12.2 it does](https://static.javadoc.io/info.cukes/gherkin/2.12.2/gherkin/formatter/model/TagStatement.html).

Check your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the Jars and added new jars and it solved this issue. Now facing new ones.